# Display results of Model in For Loop instead of Foreach Asp MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Ok so I basically have a survey wizard with 4 parts in it, I need to display 5 separate results into each, but a for loop as below, will obviously display all results and will therefore break the wizard, how can I loop through this in a for loop?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Survey.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>       
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Model is some sort of `IENumerable`

```
@{ var list = Model.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list[i].Category.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list[i].Survey.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list[i].Title)
            </td>       
        </tr>
    }
 }
```

Comment: I basically need to display: 0 to 5, then 5 to 10, then 11 - 15 then 16 - 20

Comment: @Mic, what do you mean 'between 0' ?

Comment: Sorry I mean as in 1 - 5, It is an ICollection

Comment: Ok, what happens if you try what I gave you above?

Comment: Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<STRA.Models.Question>'

Source Error:

Comment: I think I will try Model.Count() with if and else statements and see how that works out

Answer (score 1):

Go it, just used an incrementer, seems to work just fine with the Model

```
 @{
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 1 && counter < 6)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Survey.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
```